# How to develop amazon like Search inside this book by jquery

Tags: jquery

i notice one nice things that a amazon provide that is load pdf data in div and when user scroll down then load more data....in short infinite scrolling system. my question is that how could i load pdf data into div partially by jquery and when user scroll down then next few data will show in that div. here is amazon link
[http://www.amazon.com/2010-NET-Platform-Andrew-Troelsen/dp/1430225491/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1333627776&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)

just go to link and click on Search inside this book hyperlink then u see a div appear and books data loads partially into that div....if user scroll down then more data loads on demand into that div. how could i develop this type of things for any book selling site. the most challenging part is to load few data from pdf and load into div and keep the track of data load because when user scroll then rest of the few data loads again into that div.  if anyone has any idea that how to develop this type of system with jquery then please share with me. thanks

Comment: have you seen this: https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done just by using jquery

If you inspect amazon html page you will come to know that amazon is using images ([click for image](http://sitb-images.amazon.com/Qffs+v35leqGGdXjPUS3fkKsegtEDhVWKjdTnWGrt1aL4+zfPMGrKnUPI0knKYH9c17ArfSoleY=)) of pdf for display, so you need to create pdf images to display it to user. To create images use pdftohtml or imagemagick this completes the display part.

Search can be done using lucene, lucene has the ability to index pdf files so you can search the index data and get that back. Refer this [link for more info on lucene pdf index](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_index_PDF_documents.3F)

Comment: suppose my pdf has 20 pages. so just tell me do i need to convert the 20 pages to 20 images at a time or on demand basis. plzz guide. is there any sample code available which help me to load images in div and when scroll down then next images will load.

Comment: it depends on your need, if the pdf are reusable like in the case of amazon you can do it in background but if the pdf are rarely used then use an ajax call to generate the next page when user scrolls. Both are valid but you need to choose depending upon use case and user experience you are trying to provide